# Finding an angle in a triangle, given the angle bisector and some conditions.

Tags: geometry

[image]

$ABC$ is a triangle in which $\angle B= 2\angle C$. $D$ is a point on side $BC$ such that $AD$ bisects $\angle BAC$ and $AB = CD$.

What is the measure of $\angle BAC? $

I tried using angle bisector theorem, similarity, but the sides, don't **include** the angles. Also I got a relation, $3x+2\theta=180^{\circ}$, where $\angle ACB=x;\angle BAD=\theta$.

But I cannot derive one more relation, please help. 
Please don't use trigonometry, nor any constructions. We have to do without them, simply.

Comment: Please I want the answer urgently.

Comment: Please can someone, **just** point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is not a good attitude to put us in a hurry. We give help because we like it, but you should avoid abusing it.

Comment: Sorry, I am desperate right now. Thanks for the answer btw, but please see the edit.

Comment: I have already answered to that, too. You may check that if $D,E,F,G,H$ are the vertices of a regular pentagon, $DEG=ABC$ works just fine.

Comment: As an alternative, let $E$ be another point on $AD$ such that $CD=CE$. By angle chasing $\widehat{DCE}=\widehat{ACB}$, so, if $F=CE\cap AB$, $D$ is the incenter of $ACF$ and $ACF$ is similar to $ABC$. If you prove (through Ptolemy's theorem, for instance) that $ACEB$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, $\widehat{BAC}=72^\circ$ readily follows.

Comment: ?? Won't $D$ and $E$ coincide?

Comment: Come on, Aditya! $E$ is another point on the $AD$-line such that $CE=CD$, i.e. $C$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $DE$.

Comment: Ohh sorry! (y).

Comment: But still, I am damn sure there **is** a **very very** elementary approach.

Comment: Your link isn't opening, it redirects to the homepage.

Comment: http://www.theproblemsite.com/reference/mathematics/the-golden-ratio/trigonometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A simple solution:**
[image]
Let $\angle ACB=\gamma$ and $\angle BAC=2\alpha$. By assumption $\angle ABC=2\gamma$

Let $BP$ is the bisector of $\angle ABC$ where $P$ is on $AC$. 
Then $\angle PCB=\angle PBC=\gamma$. This means $PC=PB\quad (1)$. But it is also given $CD=AB\quad (2)$.

From $(1),(2)\Rightarrow \triangle ABP \simeq \triangle DCP\,\,$  (they have a common angle) $\,\,\Rightarrow AP=DP$ $\Rightarrow \angle PAD=\angle PDA=\alpha=\angle BAD$ (because $AD$ is a bisector). Therefore $PD ||AB\Rightarrow \angle PDC=\angle ABC=2\gamma\quad (3)$. But from $\triangle ABP \simeq \triangle DCP$ we also have $2\alpha=\angle BAP=\angle CDP\quad (4)$.

Finally, $(3)$ and $(4)$ give $2\alpha=2\gamma$ and from $2\alpha+3\gamma=180^o$ we find $2\alpha=72^o$

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use $2$ times the $sin$-theorem respectively for triangle $ADC$ and $ABD$ and the bisector theorem : $AB:AC=BD:DC$ together with the equality $3x + 2\theta=180^o$

Comment: Please can you restrict the use of trigonometry?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $R=1$. Then $AB=2\sin(\theta),AC=2\sin(2\theta)$ and $BC=2\sin(3\theta)$ by the sine theorem.

The bisector theorem gives:
$$CD = 2\sin(3\theta)\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{\sin(2\theta)+\sin(\theta)} = 2\sin(\theta)=AB$$
hence we have:
$$ \sin(3\theta)\sin(2\theta)=\sin(\theta)\sin(2\theta)+\sin^2(\theta) $$
or, by dividing both terms by $\sin^2(\theta)$,
$$ (4\cos^2(\theta)-1)2\cos(\theta) = 2\cos(\theta)+1 $$
so:
$$ 8\cos^3(\theta)-4\cos(\theta)-1=0$$
then $\cos(\theta)\in\left\{-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4},\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}\right\}$ or $\theta\in\left\{\frac{2\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{5},\frac{3\pi}{5}\right\}$, hence $\widehat{ACB}=\theta=\frac{\pi}{5}$ and
$$\widehat{BAC}=\pi-3\theta=\color{red}{\frac{2\pi}{5}}=72^\circ=\widehat{ABC}.$$
Do you recognize a portion of a regular pentagon?

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$\angle ADB=180^\circ -\left(\angle B+\frac{\angle BAC}{2}\right)$$
$$\angle B+\angle C+\angle BAC=180^\circ\iff 2\angle C+\angle C+\angle BAC=180^\circ$$ $$\iff \angle C=\frac{180^\circ-\angle BAC}{3}\tag 1$$$$\iff \angle B=\frac{2(180^\circ-\angle BAC)}{3}\tag 2$$

apply sine rule in $\triangle ABD$ $$\frac{\sin\angle B}{AD}=\frac{\sin \angle ADB}{AB}$$
$$\frac{\sin\angle B}{AD}=\frac{\sin \left(\angle B+\frac{\angle BAC}{2}\right) }{AB}\tag 3$$ Similarly, apply sine rule in $\triangle ADC$

$$\frac{\sin\angle C}{AD}=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\angle BAC}{2}\right)}{CD}$$
Setting $CD=AB$, we get 
$$\frac{\sin\angle C}{AD}=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\angle BAC}{2}\right)}{AB}\tag 4$$

Dividing (3) by (4), we get

$$\frac{\sin\angle B}{\sin \angle C}=\frac{\sin \left(\angle B+\frac{\angle BAC}{2}\right) }{\sin \left(\frac{\angle BAC}{2}\right) }$$
Setting the values of $\angle B$ & $\angle C$, we get 
$$\frac{\sin \left(\frac{2(180^\circ-\angle BAC)}{3}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{180^\circ-\angle BAC}{3}\right)}=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{2(180^\circ-\angle BAC)}{3}+\frac{\angle BAC}{2}\right) }{\sin \left(\frac{\angle BAC}{2}\right) }$$

$$2\cos \left(60^\circ-\frac{\angle BAC}{3}\right)=\frac{\sin \left(120^\circ-\frac{\angle BAC}{6}\right) }{\sin \left(\frac{\angle BAC}{2}\right) }$$

I hope you can solve for $\angle BAC$

Answer (score 0):

The angle bisector $AD$ has length as a harmonic mean $ 2 b c/( b+c) $

$$ 2 \theta + 3 x = \pi $$

$$ \frac{\sin \theta }{\sin x}=\frac{ b+c  }{2 b } $$

Please take it further to find  two unknowns from two equations above.